# Is it possible to associate an Elastic Network Interface to an Opswork instance?

Tags: aws-opsworks

I'd like to have the instances I create in AWS Opsworks use preconfigured Elastic Network Interfaces so that I have some predictable internal IP addresses to use when I configure all my services. I'm not seeing a way to do this in the UI yet, has anyone come up with a slick way to do this via a recipe or custom JSON?

Answer (score 0):

You can associate elastic ips with opsworks instances through opsworks api. Boto; which is a python library for aws api will allow you to do exactly what you are looking for.

Specific method to do that is:

```
associate_elastic_ip(elastic_ip, instance_id=None)
```

[Boto docs](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/opsworks.html#id33)